# How to stop making webflux calls if the previous call returns ok

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

i have just started my reactor journey, and blocked at following implementation.

```java
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Integer firstValuePresent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    x = checkDb(l.get(i));//db or any io call
    if (x.isPresent())//check for the first available value in db
    {
        firstValuePresent = l.get(i);
        break;
    }
}
//do something with firstValuePresent
```

how can i do like this in case of reactor.
I suspect that take or takeWhile can help but don't know how.
Helps are appreciated

Comment: Note that i want to check db for the values in sequential manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try thise two operators:

- `filter(Predicate<? super T> p)` - Evaluate each source value against the given Predicate.
- `next()` - Emit only the first item emitted by this Flux, into a new Mono.

like this:

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4).filter(i -> checkDb(i).isPresent()).next();
```